# How to pass arguments to a shell script using java?

Tags: java, shell

I have written a code which calls a shell script:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb2=new ProcessBuilder("/home/abhijeet/sample1.sh");
 Process script_exec = pb2.start();
 pb2.redirectError();
```

Code works for me , as it executes script.

This script takes two arguements 1: input file 2: seqs , in a pattern like:

```
 sample1.sh -ip=abc.txt --seqs=20
```

Shell script is interactive one, which asks for many parameters ,  so i have changed it's code and i will pass those values as arguements to it. So complete format should be like:

> db=abc outformat=1 threads=10 sample1.sh --ip=abc.txt --seqs=20

So how can i execute this script using java? Is there any other way to call a interactive script using java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb2=new ProcessBuilder("/home/abhijeet/sample1.sh --ip=abc.txt --seqs=20");
 Process script_exec = pb2.start();
 OutputStream in = script_exec.getOutputStream();
 in.write("abc".getBytes());
 in.write("1".getBytes());
 in.write("10".getBytes());
 in.flush();
 in.close();
```

This code writes abc, 1 and 10 to process input.

Comment: Is this code for interactive script ? I thought that might be difficult  so I have modified script and  i want to directly set those values as argument.

Comment: When you call interactive program, it waits for user input.  in.write("abc".getBytes());
 in.write("1".getBytes());
 in.write("10".getBytes()); writes the values as an user would do it.

Comment: db output and threds  are passed by this but --ip and --seqs still not working .Should i change my script and take those values also as these arguements?

Comment: As I understand --ip and --seqs are not user inputs, but program parameters. In such case you need to add them to the command or pass as arguments like fmcato wrote.

Comment: Stuck at point that if that interactive script is a long one, and it takes input somewhere in between then how can i know using inputstream that script is prompting for user input?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/index.html), it helps to run external processes in multi-platform environment.

Here is the tutorial: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the arguments in the ProcessBuilder constructor. Like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb2=new ProcessBuilder("/home/abhijeet/sample1.sh", "-ip=abc.txt", "--seqs=20");
```

You can also use a List < String  > instead.